# Why isn't scheduling working in uTorrent?

Tags: download, utorrent, scheduling

My DSL provider kindly gives me (almost) unlimited data through the night but limits my 9am-6pm usage to 2GB per month.  This is fine as I am at work during this time and means that I plan any downloads for overnight.

I enabled the scheduling feature of uTorrent, thinking that this would stop any downloading at 9am, but this didn't work and I returned home to find that it had continued downloading an additional 8GB through the day, costing me about £12.  Dang.

After checking all the settings, I tried it again at the weekend and watched as the clock rolled over the designated time, but uTorrent kept downloading.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember this happened to me too. I solved it by turning off the scheduler for all time periods and then setting it up again. Uncheck the Enable Scheduler box, check it again, 'color' all the time boxes in white (i.e. Turn off), and then color the time periods you want with green again.

Comment: Finally got round to trying this and it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I understand this happens when you downgrade to version 2.2 (as necessary to acess some trackers).
I've tried the suggestion above but it didn't work. Then I colored all the time boxes in green and pink and yes! it stopped the scheduler from downloading after hours.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

@Rosebud - This worked for me too.  I downgraded to version 2.0.4 and scheduler was set to "Turn Off" mode at 8am - but nothing happened and DLs continued no matter what I did.  I changed all of my white blocks in the scheduler to "Full Speed" green and then changed them back to white.  All torrents immediately changed to "queued".

Comment: This should really be a comment on the answer as it isn't an answer in itself